# Nivo Slider is covering my drop dorwn menu, Is it the z-index?

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, slider, z-index, nivo-slider

I'm currently working on this site http://brasco.co/LDF/ and the nivo slider is covering my drop down menu. I've fiddled with various z-index settings but can't quite locate where it might be off. Any suggestions? I'm stumped

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.  I asked the developer and he said to paste this in the CSS:

```
  .nav-menu {
        position:relative;
        z-index:9999 !important;
    }
```

It solved the problem.  Here is a link to the discussion of the problem on his site:

http://support.dev7studios.com/discussions/nivo-slider-wordpress-plugin/1002-nivo-slider-hides-dropdown-menus